# set table cell width with w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok, here's a puzzler...

I have a table that is drawn dynamically. Categories labels go in YELLOW, items labels in green.

[image]

The area where the table is located is limited, so I need to truncate long labels inside cells using jQuery plugin. The plugin allows using either numeric value for width or "auto", however I would like to add some login to determine what the numeric values should be.

Table width is 700px. 
I can also use jQuery to count how many category columns exist.
I also can determine what is the widest label in Green area. Here's my code:

```
// widest item label (GREEN)
var w = 0;
$(".tData tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > w){
        w = $(this).width();
    }
});

// count category columns (YELLOW)
var colCount = 0;
$(".tData tr:first th:gt(0)").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("colspan")) {
        colCount += +$(this).attr("colspan");
    } else {
        colCount++;
    }
});

var tableWidth = 700,
    minWidthCat  = 30,
    maxWidthCat = 100,
    minWidthItem = 100
    maxWidthItem = 300;

widthCat =  minWidthCat;
widthItem = minWidthItem;

catWmin = Math.floor((tWidth - minWidthCard) / colCount);
catWmax = Math.floor((tWidth - maxWidthCard) / colCount);

// NEED HELP HERE!!!
if () {

}

// truncate categories
$(".tData tr:first th:gt(0)").truncate({
    width: widthCat
});

// truncate items
$(".tData tr td:nth-child(1)").truncate({
    width: widthItem
});
```

Need help with logic that makes the most sense. If I  don't have to truncate I rather not set the width for **Category columns**, but they have to be **all the same width**.

Comment: You want the longest _contents_ length of the first column? Is that how I should be understanding this? otherwise if you're looking for the row width it's as simple as getting any row from that column and getting its width--that's how a table displays after all.

Comment: No, I can get the width of the longest sting in the first column. I thought that if I knew what it is it would help me determine whether to add truncation to it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can simply, set some width for the columns, say

```
700 / columnCount + 1
```

And then wrap the content in each cell within a span and set

```
overflow:none;
```

So, the content would get clipped anyway. (Unless, you also want column resizing later, this wouldn't help much)

Have you considered using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Comment: I do have overflow, but I still would like to have all Category columns width the same, regardless what it is. It just should not be shorter than minWidthCat value. No, I have not looked into jqGrid. It looks nice but a lot more complex than what I need in this project.

Comment: @santa: It's not complex. Even for small tasks like this one. Takes barely an hour to setup for the first time.